# Trying to get the maximum value every 12th element

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I am trying to get the maximum of the first axis (of a 3d array), but get the maximum for only every 12th element.

Using a random 3D numpy array (that has the first axis divisible by 12), the first axis is a size of 36. and I want to get the maximum of the first 12 elements, then 12 - 24, and then 24 - 36.

I tried:

```
## 3d array

array = np.random.rand(36,20,30)

# get the maximum for every 12 units:

maximum_every_12 = np.zeros((int(array.shape[0]/12),array.shape[1],array.shape[2]))

for i in range(12):
    maximum_every_12[i,:,:] = np.max(array[i::12,:,:],axis=0)
```

but I get an index error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1643197/1714711606.py in <module>
      8 
      9 for i in range(12):
---> 10     maximum_every_12[i,:,:] = np.max(array[i::12,:,:],axis=0)

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

How might I get the maximum value for every 12th element based on the first axis of the 3d array (size 36, 20, 30).

Comment: So you want the scalar maximum for each array of 12x20x30?

Comment: yes! every 12th element :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the size of the arrays wrong. The first axis of  `maximum_every_12` is of length `36 / 12` which is 3. Therefore you cannot iterate over `range(12)`, which fails at `i = 4`. You must iterate over `range(36/12)`.